# Tuple not returning any value

Tags: c#, linq

I am using C# with Framework 4.5 and have a function with linq as below:

```
    return (from r in m_ds.pdfDbHelper.dtEmployee.AsEnumerable()
                where Convert.ToInt32(r.Field<object>("Employee_NUMBER")) == Convert.ToInt32(dt)
                select new Tuple<string, string, string>(Convert.ToString(r.Field<object>("EMPLOYEE_TYPE"))
                                                        , Convert.ToString(r.Field<object>("EMPLOYEE_DEFVALUE"))
                                                        , Convert.ToString(r.Field<object>("EMPLOYEEID")))
               ).FirstOrDefault();
```

How can I resolve this issue?  I tried initializing the Tuple but it did not yield any resutls.

Comment: I usually use method syntax (where this will definitely work), so I'm not sure if this will work with this LINQ mode, but have you tried clicking on the `new Tuple<string, string, string>(` and pressing F9 to set a breakpoint there? You might be able to find out if it even gets that far. Also, all the `r.Field<object>` calls make me quite worried.

Comment: @Magus, I put the breakpoint and checked, functions executes but does not return any value.

Comment: Are you sure that there are records that correspond this condition: Convert.ToInt32(r.Field<object>("Employee_NUMBER")) == Convert.ToInt32(dt) ?

Comment: @Anton Yes, I executed the query manually to check whether the records exist. It does.

Comment: Did it break only within the `select` when you did that? With method syntax, you can break inside a lambda. If you are able to break inside the `select`, you can examine `r`'s properties.

Comment: @Magus Yes it did.  I will try using the Method Syntax.